# android 1.5, programmatically copy songs form /sdcard/songs to /sdcard/backup

Tags: android, backup, mp3, android-sdcard

i am using eclipse emulator and i want to copy programmatically some mp3s from **/sdcard/songs** to **/sdcard/backup**, is there any way to do so?
any help and code snippet is greatly appreciated!
thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String sourcePath= "/path/to/source/file.mp3";
        String destinationPath= "/path/to/destination/file.mp3";
        File source= new File(sd, sourcePath);
        File destination= new File(sd, destinationPath);
        if (source.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```